# XSD difference between complexContent and sequence

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

What's the difference between a `sequence` and a `complexContent` in XSD?

I'm very new to XSD, but I've read some articles and the w3schools tutorial on XSD.
I've searched a lot in the internet as well, but nowhere was the difference between the two explained.

An example would be this:

```
<xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType> 
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

vs

```
<xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType> 
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While both [`xs:complexContent`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#dcl.ctd.ctcc) and [`xs:sequence`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#declare-contentModel) can appear as child elements of [`xs:complexType`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#declare-type), they serve completely different purposes:

- Use **`xs:complexContent`** (with a `xs:restriction` or `xs:extension`
  child element) to define a type that ***restricts or extends*** another type.
- Use **`xs:sequence`** to indicate a ***sequential ordering*** of subordinate elements (or other subordinate grouping constructs).

Note that your example of `xs:complexContent` is invalid as `xs:element` cannot be a direct child of `xs:complexContent`.

**See also:**

- [Example of extending complex types in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50785402/290085)
- [The difference between <all> <sequence> <choice> and <group> in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36286056/290085)